# How to set truncate-lines for both files in ediff mode

Tags: ediff

I use a default .emacs line to truncate lines

`(setq truncate-lines t)`

However, for ediff mode I want to see the entire line for both files being compared.  Have been toggling manually at each ediff use, now trying to make that automatic in my .emacs file.

Have tried adding to existing styling lambda

```
  (add-hook 'ediff-mode-hook
     (function (lambda ()
     ...
     (setq truncate-lines nil)
  )))
```

Also trying variants

```
(toggle-truncation)
'(truncate-lines nil))
```

without success.

I note that when doing manually I have to un-truncate each of the two ediff files
individually, toggling from the main ediff command line has no effect.
So guess I somehow need to un-truncate each file individually in the
configuration file - but have no idea how to do that.

In short, how can I start up ediff mode with both files having untruncated lines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ediff-startup-hook`: define a function `my/ediff-set-truncate-lines-both-buffers` to set `truncate-lines` to `nil` in both buffers and add it to the hook. The hook is run after `ediff` has started up and set up the buffers and window configuration. It is run in the context of the control buffer where `ediff-buffer-A` and `ediff-buffer-B` are variables whose values are the respective buffers. In summary:

```el
(defun my/ediff-set-truncate-lines-both-buffers ()
  (with-current-buffer ediff-buffer-A (setq-local truncate-lines nil))
  (with-current-buffer ediff-buffer-B (setq-local truncate-lines nil)))

(add-hook 'ediff-startup-hook #'my/ediff-set-truncate-lines-both-buffers)
```

---

EDIT (in response to a comment by the OP)

- Naming objects with `my/foo` is indeed a poor person's namespace implementation (some people, including me, sometimes use an abbreviation of their name for that, e.g. `ndk/foo`). It is not necessary, but it does help avoid conflicts with built-in names. A lot of packages use a similar convention for the same purpose: `pkgname-foo`. I also find it convenient when using the name because I only ever have a few of those names, so completion is an effective way of finding those names, e.g doing `M-x my/ TAB` or `M-: (my/ TAB` or `C-h v my/ TAB` allows easy completion of the name in various situations (evaluating commands, or functions, or variables resp.)
- `#'foo` is a shorthand for `(function foo)` in the same way that `'foo` is a shorthand for `(quote foo)`. They are essentially similar in that they quote the name, preventing evaluation; the difference is that `function` conveys some additional information to the evaluator and byte-compiler that `foo` is a function object.
  See [Anonymous Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html) in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual (which you can also get to locally using the Info system: `C-h i g(elisp) RET i function RET` in this case).

Comment: Very gratified to get such a precise answer, which needless to say works.

As one who first learned emacs back in 1980's and wrote some lisp back then, but not since ~1995 and even back then my knowledge was thin, am curious about two points: () the 'my/' seems unnecessary - is its purpose to insure a separate namespace? () do not understand reason for '#', don't recall seeing anything like that before in lisp.

Comment: I added a couple of notes to the answer. `my/...` is indeed a weak attempt to namespace, but it is helpful IMO. `#'` is effectively `'` but for function names.